# Next.js project has trouble loading css from aws-amplify

Tags: next.js, aws-amplify

I have a Next.js project with aws-amplify. When I do `yarn build` I get the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
{ /Users/imyjimmy/project/node_modules/@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css:13
:root {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

And yes, I have tried adding the following at the top of `next.config.js`:

```
if (typeof require !== 'undefined') {
  require.extensions['.less'] = () => {}
  require.extensions['.css'] = file => {}
}
```

It makes no difference.

Here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "latest",
    "@material-ui/icons": "latest",
    "@material-ui/styles": "latest",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^1.1.32",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^2.3.11",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "clsx": "latest",
    "date-fns": "^2.0.0-alpha.7",
    "downshift": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "next": "latest",
    "next-with-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "url-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "casual": "^1.5.19",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same problem. However, I am not using next and create-react-app.  Did you find a solution?